# Remove surrounding text with regular expression

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace, find, expression

I have some code with many functions, each containing their own log entry. Each log entry is surrounded by an if statement. I want to remove the if statement, just leaving the log entry, which I think I can do using a regular expression with find and replace.

For example:

```
if (log.isEnabled()) {
    log.write("Log message with variable: %s ", var);
}
```

should be replaced with:

```
log.write("Log message with variable: %s", var);
```

I've tried things along the lines of `if \(log.isEnabled\(\)\) \{ (.*) }` to capture and group the expression, but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Is there an expression that can capture the log entry in the middle so that I can find/replace instead of doing it by hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you won't have any internal curly braces (the { and }) then you can use something like

```
\{\s*(.*)\s*}
```

...which according to [https://regex101.com](http://regex101.com) matches

```
log.write("Log message with variable: %s ", var);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
\bif\s*\(.*?\)\s*\{\s*([\s\S]*?);\s*}
```

Replace the matched string with `$1` or `\1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jH5mB0/1)`